# Is Pointer Casting To Satisfy Method Params A Dangerous Thing To Do?

Tags: c++, pointers, casting

This might be rather simple but I have a method that expects a parameter to be of type 
     BYTE **Ptr

And for various reasons I am using an int* (we'll call `intPtr` for this example) in the code that will call this method, so I was wondering if it is safe to do this:

```
 MethodCall((BYTE**) &intPtr, ...
```

The method locks an image buffer in place and you supply a BYTE* to it so that once it has locked the buffer it sets the pointer to point to the start of the locked buffer in memory. This is part of the Windows Media Foundation code and so cannot be easily changed to suit my int*.

Will the casting above do the job of having my `intPtr` still point to the locked buffer memory address after the call, as if it were a BYTE* as requested. Also, is there any danger to doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, this is not "safe".  Whilst a pointer-to-`T` may be converted to a pointer-to-`U` and back again, modifying it via the pointer-to-`U` is, at best, implementation-defined.

In your example, the method will modify your `int *` to point at some memory, but there's no guarantee that that it will choose some memory that is correctly aligned for `int`.  This would lead to what's known as "a big mess".

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was afraid that would be the case and though it compiles, I was almost sure it was a bad idea!

Comment: I'm supposing that `BYTE` is a character type.  Converting an `int*` to a `char*` will not modify the `int*`, and of course, the original `int*` is guaranteed to be sufficiently aligned for a `char*`.  Finally, the standard specifically allows using the results of this cast.

Comment: @James: He's not casting an `int*` to a `char*`, he's modifying an `int**` to a `char**`, and then modifying the underlying `int*` via the `char**`.  This could lead to a misaligned pointer.

Comment: @James The type definition for BYTE is an unsigned char. Are you suggesting therefore that I could do the above without any side effects.

Comment: @Oli perhaps I should find a different way in any case, such as using a 32-bit int as a container for holding 4 dereferenced bytes at a time

Comment: @Greenhouse: In practice, you'll probably be safe.  Firstly, the API method will probably be using `malloc`, which will return memory that's suitably-aligned for any data type.  Secondly, as long as you never dereference the `int *`, you won't be performing any misaligned reads/writes.  Nevertheless, the behaviour is still technically implementation-defined.

Comment: @Oli So I see.  My mistake: `int*` to `char*` (or `unsigned char*`) is fairly safe, and sometimes justified. `int**` to `char**` never; there's not even the guarantee that `int*` and `char*` have the same size.

Answer (score 0):

Practically, on Windows, this is probably going to work, since `BYTE*` and `int*` have the same size. In general though this is undefined behaviour, and there's no reason why pointers of different types should be of the same size -- the only pointer that's guaranteed to fit any other pointer is `void*`.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Would the safest thing to do be to supply the BYTE* to the method and then read in 4 bytes at a time placing them in to a 32 bit int (using it like a container) to achieve similar behaviour to just dereferencing the int pointer for reading values, ie. no modification of the values in the buffer is needed.

Comment: And `char*` is guaranteed to have the same size an representation as `void*`.

Comment: @James: Thanks, good point. Greenhouse. That sounds good; providing a `BYTE*` to the function is definitely the right start.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's dangerous thing if you aren't downcasting class pointer. It may crop in that case int value.

And in that case `BYTE**` is pointer to pointer or array of pointers, so casting it from int is dangerous and function may corrupt the other part of memory.